# How to submit a raw value (no parameter name and value pair) for a request's query string using Retrofit?

Tags: android, http, request, retrofit2

I have an API endpoint which expects an authorization code to be sent as the request's query string. The entire query string is the code, there is no parameter name and value pair, as it is usually the case.

How can I describe this using Retrofit?

I wrote this:

```
@GET("/Accounts/OauthLogin")
fun authenticaten(@Query('param') accessCode: String);
```

But instead of submitting a request that looks like `/Accounts/OauthLogin?param=<code>`, I want a request that is just `/Accounts/OauthLogin?<code>`

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Eduardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@QueryName` instead of `@Query`

https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryName.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 @GET("order/detail.json/{ordercode}")
Call<OrderDetailModel> getOrderDetails(@Path("ordercode") String ordercode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben P's answer is correct. By using `@QueryName` we can append the query without a key/val pair. This is the working way to achieve `@Query` and `@Path` without a replace block.

If you want to have something like **exampleapi.com/clients?string**

you'll want to use the following format

**Correct Way**

```
@GET("clients")
fun getClients(@QueryName()string: String): Call<ClientsModel>
```

**Incorrect Way**

```
@GET("{string}")
fun getClients(@Query("clients")@Path("string")string: String): Call<ClientsNetworkModel>
```